# Creating a report with percentage of values per quintile in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a dataset that looks something like this:

| City | Project | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | P1 | 3 |
| B | P2 | 4 |
| C | P1 | 5 |
| A | P2 | 6 |
| A | P3 | 7 |
| B | P1 | 8 |
| D | P1 | 9 |
| B | P3 | 1 |
| C | P3 | 2 |

I'm trying to create a report that calculates the percentage of projects per quintile, something like:

|  | [0-2] | (2,4] | (4-6] | (6-8] | (8-10] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | .1 | .1 | .2 | 0 |
| B | .1 | .2 | .3 | .4 | .5 |
| C | .1 | .3 | .5 | .7 | .9 |
| D | 0 | .1 | .3 | .5 | .7 |

I tried using the following code:

```
df$quantile = cut(df$Score, quantile(df$Score, seq(0,1,.2)), labels = 1:5, include.lowest = TRUE)

table(df$City,df$quantile)
```

But that just creates a table with the number of projects per quantile per city although I need a table with percentage of total number of projects per quantile per city. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can `count` number of rows within each `City` and `quantile`, calculation their ratio in each `City` and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(City, quantile = cut(Score, quantile(Score, seq(0,1,.2)), 
                         labels = 1:5, include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(n = prop.table(n) * 100) %>%
  arrange(quantile) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = quantile, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
  arrange(City)

# City    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       0    33.3     0  66.7   0  
#2 B      33.3  33.3     0   0    33.3
#3 C      50     0      50   0     0  
#4 D       0     0       0   0   100
```